# На диске занято места больше чем есть на самом деле. Ubuntu с SSD

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

Сервер Ubuntu с 500ГБ SSD. Удалил все ранее установленное и свои данные.
Смотрю, показывает,что 44ГБ занято:

```
~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   29M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/sda3       458G   44G  415G  10% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Проверяю в ncdu:

```
 ~# ncdu /
    1.1 GiB [##########] /usr
  491.5 MiB [####      ] /lib
  349.3 MiB [###       ] /backup
  321.6 MiB [##        ] /var
   52.4 MiB [          ] /boot
   28.6 MiB [          ] /run
    9.4 MiB [          ] /bin
    8.2 MiB [          ] /etc
    6.5 MiB [          ] /sbin
  600.0 KiB [          ] /root
   36.0 KiB [          ] /home
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /srv
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /tmp
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /media
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
    0.0   B [          ] /dev
```

При этом резервирование в файловой системе отключено (ранее):

```
~# sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda3   
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)
```

Вопрос: как найти эти 42ГБ данных? Куда они делись и как их удалить?